# How to make a conditional question in Sharepoint List/PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, conditional

I have a SharePoint List that I have customized with PowerApps. It has 3 questions that need to be answered only if the question before the 3 questions was answered.

So if the applicant gets to the question: Virtual Option and the applicant selects 'yes', I want the 3 following questions to be shown. But if they select 'no', I don't want them to be shown.

I've tried to use the conditional formatting but I can't figure it out. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As you are customizing the form in Power Apps, you can use the Visible property of the special question field to do what you like. Create a variable to work as the flag of visibility.

Here are articles which you may take as a starting point:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/hide-or-show-field-based-on-another-field-value/m-p/36068

https://natechamberlain.com/2019/07/18/show-hide-fields-conditionally-in-powerapps-forms-based-on-dropdown-selection/

Answer (score 0):

I am considering 1st option as Radio1.
Change visible property of all three labels and radios/input with this piece of code.

```
If(Radio1.SelectedText.Value="Yes",true,false)
```